# How to give preference order to conditions in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

I want to give preference order to conditions like if there are 3 conditions to be matched and I want total of 20 results then first it matches for first condition and if it gives 20 results then other conditions are not matched and if first conditions give less than 20 results then it matches for second condition and if total of first and second condition results is greater than 20 then it gives first 20 results and do not match for third condition and same will happen for third condition. If all the matches does not give 20 results then it combines the result of 3 conditions and add some random result to make it 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you want.  What about something like this?

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (node:Label)
WHERE node.a = 1
WITH collect(node) AS set1
OPTIONAL MATCH (node:Label)
WHERE node.a = 2
WITH set1 + collect(node) AS set2
OPTIONAL MATCH (node:Label)
WHERE node.a = 3
WITH set2 + collect(node) AS set3
UNWIND set3 AS node
RETURN node
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I want, there is a slight modification in this we have to use Optional Match instead of direct match otherwise the result of second or third match will be affected if first match gives zero result.